# Getting Status using Case statements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a new DBA I created an inventory check stored procedure. I need to check my Obsolete and Inventory on Hand Column and have the results affect my Status column on my customer table. Here is an example of the code I'm using.

```
       INSERT INTO dbo.tblCSSCustDeferred_TestNew
       ([CONTACTTYPE]
       ,[CONTACTID]
       ,[TITLE]
       ,[LASTNAME]
      ,[FIRSTNAME]
      ,[MINIT]
      ,[ADDR1]
      ,[ADDR2]
      ,[CITY]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[ZIP]
      ,[QTY]
      ,[OPID]
      ,[BENESET]
      ,[RIDEROPTION]
      ,[SEQNUM]
      ,[LOB]
      ,[FORMIDNUM]
      ,[FORMDESCR]
      ,[ENTITYNAME]
      ,[ATTN]
      ,[EMPGRPID]
      ,[NETWORKCODE]
      ,[BRAND]
      ,[FormsMgmtNum]
      ,[FormsMgmtDesc]
      ,[Electronic]
      ,[LetterHead]
      ,[Envelope]
      ,[LANGUAGE]
      ,[JURISDICTION]
      ,[EFFECTIVE DATE]
      ,[Status])

 select  [CONTACTTYPE]
      ,[CONTACTID]
      ,[TITLE]
      ,[LASTNAME]
      ,[FIRSTNAME]
      ,[MINIT]
      ,[ADDR1]
      ,[ADDR2]
      ,[CITY]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[ZIP]
      ,[QTY]
      ,[OPID]
      ,[BENESET]
      ,[RIDEROPTION]
      ,[SEQNUM]
      ,[LOB]
      ,[FORMIDNUM]
      ,[FORMDESCR]
      ,[ENTITYNAME]
      ,[ATTN]
      ,[EMPGRPID]
      ,[NETWORKCODE]
      ,[BRAND]
      ,[FormsMgmtNum]
      ,[FormsMgmtDesc]
      ,[Electronic]
      ,[LetterHead]
      ,[Envelope]
      ,[LANGUAGE]
      ,[JURISDICTION]
      ,[EFFECTIVE DATE]
         CASE  
         WHEN tsg.Obsolete = 'N' THEN 'OOS' 
         When tsg.[Inventory on Hand] = '0' THEN 'OOS'     
         else 'FulFilled'                 
       END 
       CASE   
         WHEN tsg.Obsolete = 'Y' THEN 'N/A' 
         When tsg.[Inventory on Hand] > 0 THEN 'Completed'     
         else 'OOS'               
       END   
         ,[Status]    
      FROM [CSSFulfillment].[dbo].[tblCSSCustUpdateTEST] cust left join
        [CSSFulfillment].[dbo].[tmpTSGInventoryImport] tsg on
        cust.FORMIDNUM = tsg.[Item ID]
        END
```

My problem is this query is throwing a syntax error that I can not find. here's the error message;

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 68 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

I have tired looking it up online but to no avile. Really hoping someone can lean an eyeball and help me.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Here there is no update happening u are trying to do an insert!!. Next which one is created as new column?

Comment: Hi Pradeep; my task is to compare the inventory table to the customer table to see if the column [Obsolete] on the Inventory table is 'N'= no or 'Y'= yes and if the column [Inventory on Hand] has a value of zero or a value greater than zero and have the results affect the [Status column on the customer table and be.I join the customer table and the Inventory tabl with a left join. the above code give me a new column called 'Out of Stock' which is the value that goes into the cutomer table on the [Status] column. @Ken White--how do you suggest I title the question? really new to the forum here.

Comment: @KenWhite; thanks for the advice, I have edited and changed the title.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remove my (now obsolete) comments.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma between the fields and case statements....

**Updated answer.**

just run select statement are see if it ruturn results. 
Then try to insert into table. Please look at a ,b column and replace with your desire names.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCSSCustDeferred_TestNew
       ([CONTACTTYPE]
       ,[CONTACTID]
       ,[TITLE]
       ,[LASTNAME]
      ,[FIRSTNAME]
      ,[MINIT]
      ,[ADDR1]
      ,[ADDR2]
      ,[CITY]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[ZIP]
      ,[QTY]
      ,[OPID]
      ,[BENESET]
      ,[RIDEROPTION]
      ,[SEQNUM]
      ,[LOB]
      ,[FORMIDNUM]
      ,[FORMDESCR]
      ,[ENTITYNAME]
      ,[ATTN]
      ,[EMPGRPID]
      ,[NETWORKCODE]
      ,[BRAND]
      ,[FormsMgmtNum]
      ,[FormsMgmtDesc]
      ,[Electronic]
      ,[LetterHead]
      ,[Envelope]
      ,[LANGUAGE]
      ,[JURISDICTION]
      ,[EFFECTIVE DATE], a, b -- replace a and b with your column
      ,[Status])

select  [CONTACTTYPE]
      ,[CONTACTID]
      ,[TITLE]
      ,[LASTNAME]
      ,[FIRSTNAME]
      ,[MINIT]
      ,[ADDR1]
      ,[ADDR2]
      ,[CITY]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[ZIP]
      ,[QTY]
      ,[OPID]
      ,[BENESET]
      ,[RIDEROPTION]
      ,[SEQNUM]
      ,[LOB]
      ,[FORMIDNUM]
      ,[FORMDESCR]
      ,[ENTITYNAME]
      ,[ATTN]
      ,[EMPGRPID]
      ,[NETWORKCODE]
      ,[BRAND]
      ,[FormsMgmtNum]
      ,[FormsMgmtDesc]
      ,[Electronic]
      ,[LetterHead]
      ,[Envelope]
      ,[LANGUAGE]
      ,[JURISDICTION]
      ,[EFFECTIVE DATE]
      ,   CASE  
         WHEN tsg.Obsolete = 'N' THEN 'OOS' 
         When tsg.[Inventory on Hand] = '0' THEN 'OOS'     
         else 'FulFilled'                 
       END 
      , CASE   
         WHEN tsg.Obsolete = 'Y' THEN 'N/A' 
         When tsg.[Inventory on Hand] > 0 THEN 'Completed'     
         else 'OOS'               
       END   
         ,[Status]    
      FROM [CSSFulfillment].[dbo].[tblCSSCustUpdateTEST] cust left join
        [CSSFulfillment].[dbo].[tmpTSGInventoryImport] tsg on
        cust.FORMIDNUM = tsg.[Item ID]
```

Comment: @Hiten004-- I tried your suggestion and still getting this error message Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 72 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.